# FLEX package is not installing in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: package-management, deb

I have executed below commands and there outputs are as below.

```
CMD: sudo dpkg -i flex_2.6.1_ubuntu_16.04.deb

output: 
(Reading database ... 259032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack flex_2.6.1_ubuntu_16.04.deb ...
Unpacking flex (2.6.1-1) over (2.6.1-1) ...
Setting up flex (2.6.1-1) ...

CMD: sudo apt-get install -f

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfl-dev snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.

CMD: flex --version

The program 'flex' can be found in the following packages:
 * flex
 * flex-old
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

CMD: dpkg -L flex | grep bin
output: 
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/bin
/usr/bin/bin/flex
/usr/bin/include
/usr/bin/include/FlexLexer.h
/usr/bin/lib
/usr/bin/lib/libfl.a
/usr/bin/lib/libfl.la
/usr/bin/lib/libfl.so.2.0.0
/usr/bin/lib/libfl_pic.a
/usr/bin/lib/libfl_pic.la
/usr/bin/lib/libfl_pic.so.2.0.0
/usr/bin/share
/usr/bin/share/doc
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex/AUTHORS
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex/COPYING
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex/NEWS
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex/ONEWS
/usr/bin/share/doc/flex/README
/usr/bin/share/info
/usr/bin/share/info/dir
/usr/bin/share/info/flex.info
/usr/bin/share/info/flex.info-1
/usr/bin/share/info/flex.info-2
/usr/bin/share/locale
/usr/bin/share/locale/ca
/usr/bin/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/da
/usr/bin/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/de
/usr/bin/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@boldquot
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@quot
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/eo
/usr/bin/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/es
/usr/bin/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/fi
/usr/bin/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/fr
/usr/bin/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/ga
/usr/bin/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/hr
/usr/bin/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/ko
/usr/bin/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/nl
/usr/bin/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/pl
/usr/bin/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/pt_BR
/usr/bin/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/ro
/usr/bin/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/ru
/usr/bin/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/sr
/usr/bin/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/sv
/usr/bin/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/tr
/usr/bin/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/vi
/usr/bin/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_CN
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_TW
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES
/usr/bin/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/flex.mo
/usr/bin/share/man
/usr/bin/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/share/man/man1/flex.1
/usr/bin/bin/flex++
/usr/bin/lib/libfl.so
/usr/bin/lib/libfl.so.2
/usr/bin/lib/libfl_pic.so
/usr/bin/lib/libfl_pic.so.2
```

Not sure what s going wrong here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1299077/edit) to include the complete output of `dpkg -L flex | grep bin`

Comment: What was wrong with [flex 2.6.0-11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/flex)? Why do you not want to use the repository (as simple as `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install flex`)?

Comment: Hi @N0rbert, as per protocol I should use flex 2.6.0. No other option.

Comment: @user535733 Please find the output updated in question above.

Comment: Wow, that explains it. I don't know where you got that package from, but it's badly mis-made. Everything is in /bin (that's bad). The application is in /bin/bin/ , which is why it cannot be found. Uninstall that bad package - it's worthless to you.

Comment: @user535733 the flex is not even installed.

`wk:~$ flex --version
The program 'flex' can be found in the following packages:
 * flex
 * flex-old
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>`


Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: You're going down the wrong rabbit-hole. "*program cannot be found*" is different from "*not installed*." Your output clearly shows that you installed it. But you installed a poorly-made package that put all the files into the wrong place, so the files cannot be found. We already told you how to proceed.